# build image report "need to be root" when I use root user in Dockerfile

Tags: docker

My Dockerfile looks like:

```
FROM percona/percona-xtradb-cluster-operator:0.3.0-proxysql
USER root
RUN chmod 0777 /var/lib/rpm/.dbenv.lock
```

When I run `docker build` this is the output:

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon  128.9MB
Step 1/4 : FROM percona/percona-xtradb-cluster-operator:0.3.0-proxysql
# Executing 1 build trigger
 ---> Running in 5a04ebd04891
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, ovl
ovl: Error while doing RPMdb copy-up:
[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/var/lib/rpm/.dbenv.lock'
You need to be root to perform this command.
```

Why does it say `You need to be root` even though I am setting `USER root` in the Dockerfile?

Comment: Did you run the `docker` command as `sudo`?

Comment: use sudo is the same error:

[root@tan-test-1 opt]# cat Dockerfile 
FROM percona/percona-xtradb-cluster-operator:0.3.0-proxysql
USER root
RUN /usr/bin/sudo ln -sf /usr/share/zoneinfo/Asia/Shanghai /etc/localtime

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parent image might contain an `ONBUILD` instruction which **WILL** run under the context of the user set by the `USER` command in the parent image. There is unfortunately nothing you can do about it.

You can try to build the `percona-xtradb-cluster-operator:0.3.0` docker image by cloning the [percona-xtradb-cluster-operator](https://github.com/percona/percona-xtradb-cluster-operator.git) repository and changing the Dockerfile in the `build` folder. You can change `USER root` if you wish to.

Comment: I saw similar behavior as the OP when trying to extend Docker images in this repo - https://github.com/ConSol/docker-headless-vnc-container. However no ONBUILD statements are present in the Dockerfiles. There must be a different explanation, at least for some cases.

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with your `USER root` statement in the Dockerfile. The build is failing during Step 1 (see the output --> `Step 1/4 :`), even if you change your Dockerfile to a one liner:

`FROM percona/percona-xtradb-cluster-operator:0.3.0-proxysql`

you will get the same error. So for me it looks like the base image (`percona/percona-xtradb-cluster-operator:0.3.0-proxysql`) is simply broken. I can reproduce the error.